Docker auto tagging with Github Actions
So I have been tasked with setting up an workflow that automaticly tags docker images.
So for example, the first image has to use 1.0.0 and on a new push it needs to be 1.0.1 and so on.
Is there an simple way of achieving this?
We are using an self hosted instance of github and only a few actions from github self are allowed. So it would be best if it is managed through our own instance.
I did google a lot but could not find an simple solution without using actions from github themself.

Have you tried bash?
grep your docker images and filter by image_name.
get the current tag and use it to derive the next tag.
Something in the lines of:
#!/bin/bash

# Define image name (replace with your actual image name)
IMAGE_NAME="your/project"

# Get the current version (or set a default if none exists)
CURRENT_VERSION=$(docker images | grep -w "$IMAGE_NAME" | awk '{print $2}')
[[ -z "$CURRENT_VERSION" ]] && CURRENT_VERSION="0.0.0"

# Extract major, minor, and patch numbers (assuming semantic versioning)
MAJOR_VERSION=${CURRENT_VERSION%%.*}
MINOR_VERSION=${CURRENT_VERSION#*.}
MINOR_VERSION=${MINOR_VERSION%%.*}
PATCH_VERSION=${CURRENT_VERSION#*.}

# Increment patch version
PATCH_VERSION=$((PATCH_VERSION + 1))

# Generate new version number
NEW_VERSION="$MAJOR_VERSION.$MINOR_VERSION.$PATCH_VERSION"

# Build and tag the image
docker build -t "$IMAGE_NAME:$NEW_VERSION" .

echo "Built and tagged image: $IMAGE_NAME:$NEW_VERSION"


